# Can you delete Microsoft.Web/certificates?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I'm creating LetsEncrypt SSL certificates for each of our Web App Services, then binding it to the Web App and subsequently trying to delete the previous one from our Azure resources. I notice [Remove-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/remove-azurermwebappsslbinding?view=azurermps-6.0.0) has a -DeleteCertificate flag after unbinding an SSL certificate, but I'd prefer not to unbind/delete until a new certificate has been obtained an bound.

Is there any other way that I can remove the certificates from Azure?

Answer (score -1):

I found that I can delete any resource by ID using [Remove-AzureRmResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/remove-azurermresource?view=azurermps-6.0.0).

```
Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $resourceId -Force
```

This solves my problem for now!